# Angular - How to pass / compose components into a generic component?

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

anyone know if it is possible to pass a component into another component?  I am trying to promote code re-use in our company Dev team, but hitting some blockers .
I have a Component for displaying Tabs, I want it to be generic and display what ever complex components I pass into it (components with inputs, outputs, events, implementing of components / directives etc).

eg. Maybe the Tabs will display a set of forms, or maybe a data-grid, or maybe a list, or any other component in the application.
Is this possible?  If so what is the best approach?

I have been looking at ng-template,  ng-content, dynamic components,  but not sure what the best approach is.
Anyone have any suggestions?

(seems like this is easier in React, but we are restricted to Angular only)

Comment: ng-content or ngTemplateOutlet is definitely the way to go imo. That way your tab component won't have to know anything about its content

Comment: If you want some nice examples, take a look at how angular-material components are  made. I'm not a fan of the material looks, so we only use it for rapid prototyping. But even in actual projects we use the framework they built during development of material - [Angular CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview). Material is open source, you should take a few days to learn the internals of one of the components, it will give you some insight even if  you'll want to do it differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @bertramp Looks like the NGTemplate solution is the best solution for this.  Working on a POC to present to the team.